# How to make a logistic regression with more than two attributes

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and trying to create a logistic regression for a data set. After importing the according packages I put in the following code:

```html
X = df_new3[['Type of Travel', 'Class', 'Inflight wifi service', 'Online boarding', 'Seat comfort', 'Inflight entertainment', 'On-board service', 'Leg room service']] Y = df_new3['satisfaction']

Settings show_probabilities = True

Fit the model (finding the line, solver -> mathematical tool) model = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear") model.fit(X, Y)

Apply the model acc_value = metrics.accuracy_score(model.predict(X), Y) print("Accuracy: " + str(acc_value))

#visualize results
def decision_Surface(data, target, model, surface=True, probabilities=False, cell_size=.01):
    '''
    This function creates the surface of a decision tree using the data created with this script. 
    You can change this function to plot any column of any dataframe. 
    
    INPUT:  data, 
            target,
            model (Model already fitted with X and Y , i.e. DecisionTreeClassifier or logistic regression )
            surface (True if we want to display the tree surface),
            probabilities (False by default, if True we can see the color-scale based on the likelihood of being closer to the separator),
            cell_size (value for the step of the numpy arange that creates the mesh)

    RETURNS: Scatterplot with/without the surface
    '''
    # Get bounds, we only have 2 columns in the dataframe: column 0 and column 1 
    x_min, x_max = data[data.columns[0]].min(), data[data.columns[0]].max()
    y_min, y_max = data[data.columns[1]].min(), data[data.columns[1]].max()
    
    # Create a mesh
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, cell_size), np.arange(y_min, y_max, cell_size))
    meshed_data = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    
    # Add interactions
    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        if i <= 1:
            continue

        meshed_data = np.c_[meshed_data, np.power(xx.ravel(), i)]

    if model != None:

        # Predict on the mesh with labels or probability
        if probabilities:
            Z = model.predict_proba(meshed_data)[:, 1].reshape(xx.shape)
        else:
            Z = model.predict(meshed_data).reshape(xx.shape)
            
     # Plot mesh and data
    if surface and model != None:
        if probabilities:
            # Color-scale on the contour (surface = separator)
            cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.4)
        else:
            # Only a curve/line on the contour (surface = separator)
            cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=[-1,0,1],cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.4)
    color = ["blue" if t == 0 else "red" for t in target]
    plt.scatter(data[data.columns[0]], data[data.columns[1]], color=color)
    
    # apply the function
# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=[13,15])
decision_Surface(X, Y.values.ravel(), model, probabilities=False)
plt.title("Linear model")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately the logistic regression always comes out as shown in the picture. Can anyone please help me to understand what went wrong and why the image is not showing anything?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R3xV.png)

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/mohamedharris/airline-passenger-satisfaction/data?select=train.csv

Here is the dataset. Your question is how to plot the probabilities mesh.  Normally you apply the test data set to the prediction model the across the probabilities by slicing the result array

Comment: https://favtutor.com/blogs/decision-boundary-logistic-regression  here is a link explaining what decision boundary analysis is.   The challenge is getting the x_train data into the correct shape and having enough memory to build the meshgrid.  quote: This line is known as Decision Boundary which is a boundary line created by the classifier (here, Logistic Regression) to signify the decision regions.

Comment: The decision boundary analysis uses the Principle Component Analysis clustering to plot.  It does not use the X_train dataset.,  PCA have two components.

Comment: train your model on x_train_pca data that has been pca.fit and transformed

Answer (score 0):

use the principle component analysis dataset to create your decision boundary analysis grid.  It works nicely. see (https://favtutor.com/blogs/decision-boundary-logistic-regression)

```
df=pd.read_csv("airline_train.csv")

encoder=LabelEncoder()
df['Customer Type Enc']=encoder.fit_transform(df["Customer Type"])
df['Type of Travel Enc']=encoder.fit_transform(df["Type of Travel"])
df['Gender Enc']=encoder.fit_transform(df["Gender"])
df['Class Enc']=encoder.fit_transform(df["Class"])
df['Target']=encoder.fit_transform(df["satisfaction"])
df.drop(["Customer Type","Type of Travel","Gender","Class","Unnamed: 0","satisfaction"],inplace=True,axis=1)
df.set_index("id",inplace=True)
#,"Type of Travel","Inflight wifi service"]])
print(df.columns)
print(df)

decimal_cols=["Age","Flight Distance"]
for col in decimal_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())

other_cols=[x for x in df.columns if not x in decimal_cols]
for col in other_cols:    
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].value_counts().index[0])
 
X_Columns=  [x for x in df.columns if x!="Target"]
X=df[X_Columns]
y=df["Target"]
X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=42)

def plot_scatter(model, X_train_pca,y_train, X_test_pca,y_test, title=None, figsize=(10, 10)):
    """
    Plot the decision boundary of a logistic regression model.
    """
    
    x_min, x_max = X_train_pca[:, 0].min() - 1, X_train_pca[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X_train_pca[:, 1].min() - 1, X_train_pca[:, 1].max() + 1

    xx_train, yy_train = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                                 np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))

    Z_train = model.predict(np.c_[xx_train.ravel(), yy_train.ravel()])
    Z_train = Z_train.reshape(xx_train.shape)


    x_min, x_max = X_test_pca[:, 0].min() - 1, X_test_pca[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X_test_pca[:, 1].min() - 1, X_test_pca[:, 1].max() + 1

    xx_test, yy_test = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                               np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))

    Z_test = model.predict(np.c_[xx_test.ravel(), yy_test.ravel()])
    Z_test = Z_test.reshape(xx_test.shape)
    
    plt.figure(figsize = (20, 6))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.contourf(xx_train, yy_train, Z_train)
    plt.scatter(X_train_pca[:, 0], X_train_pca[:, 1], c = y_train, s = 30, edgecolor = 'k')
    plt.xlabel('Training 1st Principal Component')
    plt.ylabel('Training 2nd Principal Component')
    plt.title('Scatter Plot with Decision Boundary for the Training Set')
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.contourf(xx_test, yy_test, Z_test)
    plt.scatter(X_test_pca[:, 0], X_test_pca[:, 1], c = y_test, s = 30, edgecolor = 'k')
    plt.xlabel('Test 1st Principal Component')
    plt.ylabel('Test 2nd Principal Component')
    plt.title('Scatter Plot with Decision Boundary for the Test Set')
    plt.show()
 

columns = X_train.columns
scalerx = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scalerx.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns = columns)

X_test_scaled = scalerx.transform(X_test)
X_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_test_scaled, columns = columns)

pca = IncrementalPCA(n_components = 2)
X_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test_scaled)

model = LogisticRegression(C = 10).fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
plot_scatter(model,X_train_pca,y_train,X_test_pca,y_test,"Decision Boundary Analysis")
```